# A bank application mentioned I opened a home loan recently. I never did. Should I be worried?

Tags: united-states, california, credit-history, identity-theft

I've been looking to move away from Evil Bank Corporation for a while now, and in the process of applying for New Shiny Bank they wanted to verify my identity by asking for my social and asking for some pertinent financial information that only I would know. No big deal.

The application mentioned I opened a home loan late last year and asked who I opened it through and how much I was spending on it. This *is* a big deal, since I never did such a thing.

According to some [identify theft](http://www.pacer.org/publications/possibilities/protect-your-identity/89-what-should-i-do-if-i-think-my-identity-has-been-stolen.html) articles I found, I should place a fraud alert on my credit reports and with my bank if I even *suspect* I've been a victim of identity theft.

But is this something I should look *actually* look into? Could this be the case of a false positive on the bank's end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this was part of a verification of identity I wouldn't worry about it.  They often include some fake data, recognizing that data as yours fails the verification.

Answer (score 7):

To resolve your concern, you can check.  As you listed a United States location, you are entitled to a free credit report from each of the big three bureaus via [annualcreditreport.com](https://www.annualcreditreport.com/index.action).  This is the portal mandated by the Department of Commerce; for various lobbying reasons, the alternatives with the word "free" in the domain name are more accurately "freemium"